# Kenmotsu - rotational surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

I was wondering if someone knows which is the parameterization that we made in these cases. I calculated till $$Z(s)=\left(\frac{1}{2iH}(1-e^{-2iHs})+C\right)e^{2iHs},$$ but can't figure out what parameterization was done after that and why we have the following values ​​for $y(s)$ and $x^{'}(s)$!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why a differential geometry tag? Is the definition of a Kenmotsu manifold remotely relevant?

Comment: Are you by chance asking about the paper K. Kenmotsu, _Surfaces of revolution with prescribed mean curvature_, Tôhoku Math. J. **32** (1980), 147--153...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang , yes ! As guidance I have a book called :"Surfaces with
Constant Mean Curvature K. Kenmotsu ,pages 39-42" I need to determine where are the results coming from. the results are written quite directly and I don't understand, and I have to write them step by step. And I got stuck in the case where H is a constant(other than 0) because I don't understand what parameterization was chosen to write the final result.

Comment: I don't have any special insight beyond the calculations in [Kenmotsu's paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Katsuei-Kenmotsu-2/publication/38369457_Surfaces_of_revolution_with_prescribed_mean_curvature_with_4_figures/links/5476735f0cf29afed614226c/Surfaces-of-revolution-with-prescribed-mean-curvature-with-4-figures.pdf). As is commonly the case, $(x(s), y(s))$ is an arclength parametrization of the profile curve; he defines $Z(s) = y(s)(y'(s) + ix'(s))$, shows $Z' -2iHZ - 1 = 0$, and deduces the expressions after two pages of calculation with judicious choices of auxiliary function.